# How does Fine Uploader determine how and when to resume a multi-part upload to Amazon S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, local-storage, fine-uploader

I have working an example of using the multi-part functionality of Fine Uploader with Amazon S3.  However I would like to know how it should be used.  I see that if I break an upload of a large file, and I reload the page and specify the same file again, the upload will resume.  But how is the resume recalled?  Is it via a session cookie?  If the user completely deletes all cookies, and history, can the resume still work?  What needs to persist in order to resume a broken upload?  Is it all dependent on the key generated for the object?  As long as the key is the same?  Can you provide some scenarios in which the resume upload works and when it would not?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resume feature exists in Fine Uploader S3, and Fine Uploader for traditional endpoints.  For traditional endpoints, cookies are used to persist information about the progress of a chunked upload.  However, Fine Uploader S3 uses [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

After each chunk is successfully uploaded to S3, Fine Uploader S3's XHR upload transport handler persists current state information for that file in `localStorage` represented as an item.

The key of that `localStorage` item is made up of the following data:

1. file name
2. file size
3. maximum chunk size
4. S3 bucket name

The value of the `localStorage` item is an `Object` (stored as a string) with the following properties:

1. file name
2. file size
3. file UUID
4. S3 key name
5. # of bytes successfully uploaded
6. Current time/date
7. Total # of chunks/parts
8. Last chunk index successfully uploaded
9. The S3 assigned upload ID (returned from S3 during the original "Initiate Multipart Upload" REST call - this is a required piece of each upload request)
10. A mapping of part indexes to etag values for all successfully uploaded parts, which is information that Fine Uploader S3 must include with the "Complete Multipart Upload" REST request, which is sent after the last part is uploaded (asking S3 to combine all parts).

When the "start upload" signal is received by Fine Uploader S3's internal XHR upload handler, it calculates the key of the file to be uploaded (using the items from the first list above).  If an item exists is `localStorage` (on the current domain/origin), then the persisted data is used to resume the upload.

Note that all expired `localStorage` items are removed during initialization of the Fine Uploader S3 instance.  An item is expired if the date property (see the 2nd list above) is more than 7 days old.  This value is configurable though, via the [`resume.recordsExpireIn` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options-s3.html#resume-option).

You can see all of this logic and more in gory detail by peering at the [Fine Uploader S3 upload handler module source code](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/client/js/s3/handler.xhr.js).